# Open google document in a compact form / switching to a compact form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my project I load a google document into a separated div.
Google document interface includes a button which hides the menu and
switches the view to a more compact form.

My question is - is it possible to switch to a compact view with the javascript?

I can open document in a preview mode
[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d//preview](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%3Cyour_document_id%3E/preview)
but it is not very usefull (compact mode is much better)

Button that is responsible for switching to compact view has the id **viewModeButton** but the following method does not work:

```
$("#viewModeButton").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Due to the same-origin policy it is not possible to execute JavaScript code to interact with contents inside an iframe from a domain that it does not share.*

#### Explanation:

As it appears you have already discovered, the same-origin policy is a critical web application security policy dating back to 1995 which restricts the execution of scripts from one web page from interacting with another ***unless the two webpages share the domain***.

`http://subdomain.domain.com/some/path.html` and `http://subdomain.com/som/other/path.html` would be able to interact with each other under this policy as the protocols, ports, and domains are all shared between them. Changing any of these though, would result in a failure of the script interaction:

**Using the example domain `http://subdomain.domain.com/path.html`:**

- `http://subdomain.domain.com/path2.html` will work as only the path differs.
- `https://subdomain.domain.com/path.html` will **not** work as the protocols differ.
- `http://subdomain.domain.com:894/path.html` will **not** work as the ports differ.
- `http://subdomain2.domain.com/other-path.html` will **not** work as the hosts differ.

**Note:** Internet Explorer has a couple of exceptions where scripts will run for the cases where only the ports differ, or if the two domains are intranet domains, but this is non-standard.

#### Reasoning:

For cases like yours, it is relatively benign if scripts access other domains for click emulation or alert popups - but in other cases where personally identifiable or data payment information is being stored or transmitted, strict separation of the two domains is important to *keep private information private*.

#### References:

- [Same-origin policy - MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
- [The Document Object Model (DOM) - MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- [Make Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Forms public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible due to the same-origin policy.